# How do I handle On Load event?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `load_words` function which I would like to be executed when the application starts.

In C#, I would create the following method:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadWords()
}
```

How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        ### put HERE the "onLoad()" code ###
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    #    self.create_widgets()

...

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('600x900-0+0') # 120 * 50 ppixels in top right corner of desktop
    app = Application(root)
    app.master.title('Sample application')

    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

See also [here](https://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/Events) for more about events in tkinter.

Happy coding :) . And don't get disappointed using tkinter. There are many other options of GUIs you can use in Python like e.g. [wxPython](http://wxwidgets.org) which using will be probably easier for a C# programmer.

Comment: Got it! @Claudio